# Conditional within def __str__(self) in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
```

As you can see, both `user` and `name` are nullable. This is because a profile might be linked to a user or not. If it is not, then only the `name` field is provided. How can I return `name` if the profile is not linked to user, and the `user.name` properties if it is? This:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return
        if self.user:
            f"{self.user}'s profile"
        else:
            self.name
```

returns a `__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)` error.

**Solution**

In the end I've used a slightly modified version of @Max Malysh's accepted answer:

```
def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s profile" if self.user_id != None else f"{self.name}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.user:
        return f"{self.user}'s profile"
    else:
        return f"{self.name}"
```

or

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user}'s profile" if self.user else f"{self.name}"
```